# GraphQL Schema for mongoose Mixed type (Schema.Types.Mixed)

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, graphql

I have a Mongoose schema with the following structure:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const PropertySchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    name: {
        type: String
    },
    description: {
        type: String
    },
    value: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed
    },
    unit: {
        type: String
    },
});

export default mongoose.model('Property', PropertySchema);
```

I need to build a GraphQL query for the given data. How do I handle the Mixed type for the `value` property ?

Here is my try:

```
import NodeInterface from '../interfaces';

import PropertyModel from '../../models/Property';

const fields = {
    id: {
        type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLID),
        resolve: (obj) => dbIdToNodeId(obj._id, "Property")
    },
    name: {
        type: GraphQLString
    },
    description: {
        type: GraphQLString
    },
    value: {
        type: <<< What to use here ?
    },
    unit: {
        type: GraphQLString
    }
};

export const PropertyType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Property',
    description: 'Property',
    interfaces: () => [NodeInterface],
    isTypeOf: (value) => value instanceof PropertyModel,
    fields: fields
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GraphQL Schema to handle mixed types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34232966/graphql-schema-to-handle-mixed-types)